# FFmpeg: Windows vs Linux issues

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have run into an issue that I am pretty sure I have narrowed down to FFmpeg.

I have a Flask app that restreams live streams using FFmpeg.

```
...

@app.route("/play/", methods=["GET"])
def play():
    def streamData():
        try:
            with subprocess.Popen(
                ffmpegcmd,
                stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            ) as ffmpeg_sb:
                while True:
                    chunk = ffmpeg_sb.stdout.read(1024)
                    if len(chunk) == 0:
                        break
                    yield chunk
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            ffmpeg_sb.kill()

    return Response(streamData())

...
```

I am using the following command.

`ffmpeg -loglevel panic -hide_banner -i <URL> -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts pipe:`

When I run my Flask app on Windows, both VLC and TVHeadend play the piped output perfectly.
However under Linux only VLC will play the piped output. I can get TVHeadend to play the stream from Linux, but it requires me to enable the AV Library option in TVHeadend, which I want to avoid. I have tested this using WSL (Ubuntu) and Docker (alpine + Ubuntu) on my Ubuntu server where the app will live.

I can only assume its because FFmpeg behaves differently between Windows and Linux? I have tried several different version of FFmpeg... So I don't think its a version issue.

The version of FFmpeg I am currently using on Windows is this one https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ but I experienced the same success on older versions, so again, I don't think its a version number issue.

Can anyone suggest how I can go about finding out what the cause is?
Is it possible that some default values differ between Windows and Linux?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You could try to call ffmpeg in a command line on Windows and Linux to write the same input to a file and compare the written files. Similarly to download them through your flask app on both OSs and compare these files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Surely I would want to use a file rather than a live stream as the live streams will be different due to the nature of it being live? How would I compare them?

Comment: ffmpeg on different system can be compiled with different libraries which support different formats and functions. Systems may have also installed different libraries and ffmpeg may work differently.

Comment: The windows version I use lists the config settings... Is it possible to copy those and compile FFmpeg myself on Linux? Or do different OS's require different libraries?